# sshfs mounted directory becomes unresponsive

Tags: connection, sshfs

I've mounted a directory via sshfs:

```
sshfs <user>@<host>:/var/www <host>/
```

However, after a few hours, the "something" happens, and I can no longer use the mounted directory.  Symptoms are similar to when an `nfsmount`ed server becomes unavailable: ls fails, cd fails, etc.

I've attempted

```
sshfs -o reconnect <user>@<host>:/var/www <host>/
```

but that never responded.

Does anyone know how I can either unmount the directory, and remount it, or force sshfs to reconnect to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, unmount-remount is easy enough

```
fusermount -u ~/mountpoint
sshfs user@host:/dir ~/mountpoint
```

Done! As a sidenote, do you have ssh keepalive set to no on your server? You might simply be getting timed out.